# Vue DatePicker resets manually input value when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, datepicker

I am clicking on date to type
but accidentally clicking outside after clicking inside the field
the value(Duedate) becoming null
that's why date binded is resetted
before calling the changeDueDate()

```
<datepicker
  :format="customFormatter
  @input="changeDueDate()
  :typeable="true"
  v-model="Duedate"
></datepicker>
```

I want to know why

i am using vue datepicker

Comment: Can you share the package link you are using for date picker?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#usage

Comment: i just wanted use typing and selecting both the date